# Android studio Recyclerview using ListAdapter crash because IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm using ListAdapter in my Recyclerview, most time it work normally, but when currentList size is 0, and I `submitList(new ArrayList(myNewList))`, my app crash, but if I use `submitList(new ArrayList(myNewList), ()->adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()))`, it won't crash. What is the problem?

Below is my code

Adapter:

```
public Adapter(Context context){
        super(new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Relation>() {
            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Relation oldItem, @NonNull Relation newItem) {
                return oldItem.getCustomerId().equals(newItem.getCustomerId());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Relation oldItem, @NonNull Relation newItem) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        this.context = context;
}

public void setSize(int size){
        this.size = size;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        if(size == 0){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(size > 0){
            return size;
        }
        return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(size == 0){
            return TYPE_EMPTY;
        }
        else{
            return TYPE_ONE;
        }
    }
```

And I use viewModel to observe change:

```
customerRelationObserver = list ->{
            Adapter.setSize(list.size());
            Adapter.submitList(list, ()->adapter.notifyDataSetChanged());
        };
```

Below is error log

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionEmptyViewHolder{c491228 position=1 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{ba4f60 VFED..... ......I. 56,192-1244,338 #7f0a032d app:id/relationRecyclerView}, adapter:Adapter@7c33c19
```